# How do i get my code to return the result on time

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have this function, I am trying to get favorite movies, from a particular end point, Using angular. After getting all the movie list,  from inside a class method, when I try to consume the list, I see that the list is not available.

This is what i have tried.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
    import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { IMovie } from './welcome/welcome-page/movies-model';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
     export class FavoriteMoviesService {
        movieList: IMovie[];
        constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
      }

      getFavMovies(id: number) {
        let getMovies = () => {
          return this._http.get('../assets/movies.json').pipe(
          tap(response => console.log(response))
          ).subscribe(response => response = this.movieList)
       }
         getMovies();
         let chosenMovie = this.movieList? this.movieList.find(movie => movie.id == id): Array(null)
         console.log(chosenMovie)
         }   
      }
```

I really don't understand the flow of the programme, I thought that the movieList property as been set when the function getMovies() was called but the local variable chosenMovie is not getting the desired value.
Please any explanation on this behaviour?

Comment: Your ```getMovies``` function is asynchronous, while your ```chosenMovie``` gets executed sync chronously, without waiting for completion of  ```getMovies```. Therefore you are getting ```chosenMovie``` empty

Comment: You are discarding the response, change `.subscribe(response => response = this.movieList)` to `.subscribe(response => this.movieList = response)`

Answer (score 2):

You should wait for the response before you utilize the moviesList. Modify the function as below so that you process the response after it is received.

```
      getFavMovies(id: number) {
        this._http.get('../assets/movies.json').pipe(
          tap(response => console.log(response))
          ).subscribe(response => {
              this.movieList = response;
              let chosenMovie = this.movieList? this.movieList.find(movie => movie.id == id): Array(null);
              console.log(chosenMovie)
            })
      }
```

Comment: With this, I means that I have to write a whole bunch of codes on the subscribe body

Answer (score 0):

You are doing  it wrong by assigning `this.moviesList` value to `response` obtained after http call by doing : `response = this.movieList`:

```
let getMovies = () => {
          return this._http.get('../assets/movies.json').pipe(
          tap(response => console.log(response))
          ).subscribe(response => this.moviesList = response.data; // whatever is your object for movielist)
       }
```

Since the `movieList` is empty, it will return empty response and hence no result.

You should return the `response` in subscribe block.

Comment: I did return the response, but how do i get the value so as to consume it.

Comment: when I returned the response and assigned the function to a variable and logged out the value on a console, I got a weird object that look nothing like the data i expected. This is what i got:  Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}

Comment: you can check the response value and get the desired object from it and assign it to `this.moviesList`